# Can I declare app-wide acronym substitution for voice-over?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Being a data-centric app, I have lots of german legal **acronyms** for german laws in my app. An english example would probably be "Cx" being read as "Constitution". I have a handful of those acronyms, they can be found in various text fields, all across my app.

**Is there a way to declare app-wide voice-over pronunciation rules for these acronyms as a developer?** I would rather not implement manual text substitution for 100+ UITextViews...

Research so far:

- [This](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1136.html) document, talking about choosing systemwide acronym substitution, but as an end user. (under "Changing pronunciations in the Speech Dictionary")
- [UIAccessibilityReadingContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityreadingcontent) seems to be talking about a general Design-Pattern, not about word level optimisation of the output.

Answer (score 1):

I’m unaware of an app-wide pronoun citation table for VO. An easy workaround is to use a custom subclass of `UITe xtView` and override `accessibilityLabel` to return the label with the substituted phrase for each language’s abbreviations.

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm trying to avoid  Since it would add a line per textview and I have about 30 in several pages...